# How to restore a Nandroid backup without TWRP?

Tags: twrp, nandroid, oneplus

I have bricked my OnePlus 5 device (black screen, blue LED, bootloader locked, no TWRP on my device). I have tried almost everything (sideloading the official OnePlus firmware through adb, using the MSM Download tool to flash the .ops file - The flash is successful but I get the black screen, blue LED at boot again), none of it seems to work. But, I'm not prepared to give up.

So, I was thinking maybe if I get my hands on another OnePlus 5 device  and take a Nandroid backup of the device using TWRP with the OEM unlock option enabled in Developer Settings and use this backup to flash my original bricked OnePlus 5. The point of taking a backup with the OEM unlock option enabled in developer settings is to somehow load this Nandroid backup on my bricked OnePlus 5 device (so that I at least can unlock my bootloader and explore other options of restoring my device by flashing a custom recovery).

**Now, the question is - If I manage to take a Nandroid backup of another working OnePlus 5 device, what are my options of loading this Nandroid backup on my bricked device (as I don't have TWRP on the bricked device).**

Any guidance on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't BECAUSE of locked bootloader